# DataBase Data interity with four tables

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have four tables (products, brands, colors and colorproducts)
- a product has one brand
- a color has one brand
- a colorproduct has one product and one color

The problem I see is that a colorproduct references a color and a product and that both of them reference a brand.
What happens if a product and a color referenced by the same colorproduct reference 2 different brands?

I suppose my database is bad but I don't know how to fix it.
I use Doctrine 2 ORM and I have read in their documentation that the use of composite primary keys should be avoided if possible. Would you see a solution to my problem?

Thank you

Comment: Why would a color have a brand?

Comment: What @DanyCaissy said is true: it's strange to say the least. However if you must implement it that way and if a product has one brand and a color has one brand and a constraint is that a color-product combination has the same brand as the product and the color then why don't you store the reference to the brand in the colorproduct table instead of in each individual table?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that a brand having a color is unnecessary.

It gives you two choices, store the brand in the product, or store the brand into the colorproduct.

I think it would make sense to store the brand only in the product and it would solve your issue altogether, as color is entirely irrelevant to the brand, so associating a brand to a colorproduct doesn't necessarily make sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's important for me that each color has a brand because different brands have different colors (for example, brand A might have Dark Red available while brand B might have only Cerise Red available). When I add a product, I want to be proposed only the colors available in the brand of the product.

Comment: Then your database structure is wrong, colors should never have a brand, that's for sure, you can add a different table that handles which brand is allowed to have which color instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will go for that and add a Color/Brand table